# How to make two input field required and accept value from one in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to add the values for the seller but when user want to add the seller not available in the list he can add other seller like following image.
[image]

when user select the other one text box will show to enter the new seller name. And now i want to add the required validation in server side other wise this field is not required.

Thank you.

Comment: write the below code in your controller  `$this->form_validation->set_rules('sellerId', 'seller', 'required')` followed by `$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`

Comment: Your going to need some JavaScript to hide/show the seller name field.

Comment: Will try this and back to you @NN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this using following code on controller.

```
if($warehouseArr['seller_id']=='other')
                    {
                        $this->oversight->validation[]=array('field' => 'inward[ohterseller]','label' => 'Other Seller','rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]');
                        $this->oversight->validation[]=array('field' => 'inward[seller_codestock]','label' => 'Seller Code','rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]');
                    }

            $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->oversight->validation);
```

`$warehouseArr['seller_id']` is post value of the seller select tag.